Jenkins administratively disabled user in LDAP causing false negatives
We updated/reinstalled our companys Jenkins and ran into false negatives caused by LDAP + an administratively disabled user. At first I thought it's caused by our mail-notifications and ldap cant get the email of this user, but I disabled all notifications and the problem still occurs.
Everytime a build is triggered by SVN and the administratively disabled user is inside of the commit-list, we get a false negative. We are getting visual bugs, when the user is inside the list of changes.

Log right before the error:
...
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14:28 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-16T09:34:13+02:00
...

followed by:
FATAL: org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException: The user "userxyz" is administratively disabled.
org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException: The user "userxyz" is administratively disabled.
    at hudson.security.UserAttributesHelper.checkIfUserEnabled(UserAttributesHelper.java:92)
    at hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm$LDAPUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(LDAPSecurityRealm.java:1319)
    at hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm$DelegateLDAPUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(LDAPSecurityRealm.java:1232)
    at hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm.loadUserByUsername2(LDAPSecurityRealm.java:765)
    at jenkins.security.UserDetailsCache$Retriever.call(UserDetailsCache.java:170)
    at jenkins.security.UserDetailsCache$Retriever.call(UserDetailsCache.java:159)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4955)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2328)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2187)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2081)
Caused: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2087)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4036)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4950)
    at jenkins.security.UserDetailsCache.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsCache.java:127)
    at hudson.model.User$UserIDCanonicalIdResolver.resolveCanonicalId(User.java:1262)
    at hudson.model.User$CanonicalIdResolver.resolve(User.java:1203)
    at hudson.model.User.get(User.java:530)
    at hudson.model.User.getOrCreateByIdOrFullName(User.java:593)
    at hudson.model.User.get(User.java:574)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet$LogEntry.setUser(SubversionChangeLogSet.java:305)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogParser.parse(SubversionChangeLogParser.java:92)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogParser.parse(SubversionChangeLogParser.java:43)
    at hudson.scm.ChangeLogParser.parse(ChangeLogParser.java:57)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calcChangeSet(AbstractBuild.java:947)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getChangeSet(AbstractBuild.java:915)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getChangeSets(AbstractBuild.java:929)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.calculateCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:136)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calculateCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:353)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.getCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:93)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:342)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.calculateCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:133)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calculateCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:353)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.getCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:93)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:342)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.calculateCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:133)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calculateCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:353)
    at jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM.getCulprits(RunWithSCM.java:93)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:342)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:715)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1918)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)

I tried:

disabled all notifications (email, irc, webhook)
updated all plugins
checked my LDAP settings (same as before reinstall)

Is there a way to ignore this user? Is the problem caused by LDAP, SVN or both in combination?
Edit:
Found an old entry addressing the same problem Jenkins Jira

I am now answering my own question, but maybe my solution can help someone.
In short, patch the plugin by yourself. GitHub SVN-Plugin
try-catch in SubversionChangeLogSet (Line 305) & SubversionChangeLogParser (Line 92)
Steps

Visit the GitHub of the subversion-plugin Link
Clone Project
Open Project
add try-catch in SubversionChangeLogSet (L. 305) & SubversionChangeLogParser (L. 92)
generate .hpi
install plugin via [YOUR_JENKINS_URL]/manage/pluginManager/advanced
Deploy + safeRestart

